# Removing iCloud Drive memory usage

Tags: icloud, memory

I've been searching on and off for quite awhile to find where iCloud Drive is using up 4 GB of my storage. I seldom use iCloud and do not have many things in my in Files folder. How can I delete this waste of space?

[image][image][image]

Comment: You don‘t have iCloud Drive activated on your phone.  Do you have other devices which use iCloud Drive?

Comment: No there are no other devices. But that's the point...how can it have 4GB when it's not even activated?

Comment: You could active it and then just have a look what's in there. Might give a clue.

Comment: I did. A lot of the apps were turned on. I then turned all of them off, restarted my phone and checked the storage once more. It was still at 4GB.

Comment: With the Drive turned on, you should be able to use Files to see what‘s on it.

Comment: I already know what's on the Files app. I can use Files with or without iCloud Drive being turned on.

Comment: Sure you can, but if you want to have a look what kind of Documents are stored in the iCloud Drive you need to enable it so that Files can access it. Otherwise you only see local files in Files.

Comment: Ok I just turned the Drive on again. Do you know where I could see a change in the Files?

Comment: "iCloud Drive" should show up now as one of the "Speicherorte" in Files

Comment: Thanks. Just checked it and it's unfortunately empty. Still have no idea where these 4GB are.